# undefined fields of a structure passed to a thread as a param

Tags: c

I have a structure declared and allocated in this way

```
typedef {
      char* a; char* b; int c; int d; FILE *e;
} t;
[...]

    ready= malloc(sizeof(t));
    strncpy (ready->a, ss1, length);
    strncpy (ready->b, ss2, length);
    ready->c= f; ready->d= g;
    ready->e= fopen(file, "w");
```

that I want to pass to a thread with

```
pthread_create(thread_id, NULL, worker_start, &ready);
```

when I begin to do some stuff in the thread function it's clear that the fields that I had initialized in the main before calling the create are not defined in the thread.

```
void* worker_start(void *param) {
    t *current;

    current = (t*) param;
    ...
}
```

What's wrong with the code? Am I doing something bad here?

Comment: You don't show it in your code, but you _do_ allocate memory for the strings as well?

Comment: There's a `struct` keyword missing after your `typedef`. NEVER TYPE YOUR CODE. ALWAYS CUT AND PASTE. Sorry for shouting.

Comment: what do you mean by "not defined"?

Comment: I do allocate memory for the strings and
I'm sorry for the missing code

Comment: with not defined I mean that the result of a printf of the strings field is something like �@��˿��˿: and the numbers are not the numbers I expect to have here. And writing in the file give me Seg Fault!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're passing the pointer to the thread, you pass it as a pointer to  pointer (due to you using the address-of operator `&`). You don't need to do that, and in the thread function you don't treat it as a pointer-to-pointer but just plain pointer.

Remove the ampersand (`&`) when creating the thread and things should work much better.

Comment: this sounded a good solution for me. but, i'm sorry my friend, it doesn't work ! :(

Comment: @Janinho67 There's an easy thing you can do to check that it's the right pointer you send to the thread: `printf("%p\n", ready);` Do the same in the thread, and compare the two pointers. If not equal you are doing something wrong. Also check that you don't `free` any pointers before using them.

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that fileds a and b are pointers to a char and do not allocate memory for the characters.

Either just point them at the strings

```
ready->a =  ss1;
ready->b =  ss2;
```

or duplicate the strings

```
ready->a = strdup( ss1 );
ready->b = strdup( ss2 );
```

Another issue is as per @JoachimPileborg's answer

Answer (score 0):

Where do `ready->a` and `ready->b` point to? Looks like your writing via uninitialized pointers.

Comment: That is not the point. The point is, are the members a and b initialized? You can't use an uninitialized pointer as the destination for a strcpy().

Answer (score 0):

As Joachim Pileborg said, you should not pass a pointer to pointer.

just do :

`pthread_create(thread_id, NULL, worker_start, ready);`

And don't forget to use the keyword STRUCT :

```
typedef struct t_type {
 char* a; char* b; int c; int d; FILE *e;
} t;
```